# Any advice on starting a basic react project?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've tried looking this up for an hour now on Google/Youtube and all I find is learn my first react type tutorials. All these videos and blogs leave the src folder completely untouched as used by:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

And they never do any edits to the basics.

I've done several tutorials on react and jsx and I want to start my next app "as a dev would". I will eventually move on to broilerplates, but I really want to know good practices for starting a new React Project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React.js [docs](https://en.reactjs.org/) is good enough. There is small examples [here](https://tr.reactjs.org/community/examples.html)